# Undelete request for "Why is HttpContext.Current null"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, undelete-request

I have edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18384253/263693) so that it is no longer a primarily-link answer. I get an error message when I vote to undelete; could a moderator undelete?

Comment: Good edit; Kudos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on what Mat said, only diamond moderators can undelete answers which were deleted by diamond moderators.

Custom flag your answer, explain that you've edited the answer and improved it, and that it should no longer be deleted.